# how to generate data from beta-Liouville distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, simulation

I want to test my model following the beta liouville distribution, so as a synthetic data, I need generate data from this distribution. can anyone mathematically tell me how to calculate it?
this is the formula
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Answer (score 2):

Extracting the important bits from this density, with new notations,
$$p(\mathbf x) \propto\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{\alpha_i-1}\left[ 1-x_1-\cdots-x_k\right]^{\alpha_{k+1}-1} \left[ 1-x_1-\cdots-x_k\right]^{\beta}\mathbb I_{\mathcal S_k}(\mathbf x)=\tilde{p}(\mathbf x)$$
where $\mathcal S_k$ denotes the $k$-dimensional simplex
$$\mathcal S_k=\left\{\mathbf x\in\mathbb R_+^k\,;\ \sum_{i=1}^k x_i\le 1\right\}$$
shows that
$$\tilde{p}(\mathbf x)\le \tilde{q}(\mathbf x)=\prod_{i=1}^k x_i^{\alpha_i-1}\left[ 1-x_1-\cdots-x_k\right]^{\alpha_{k+1}-1}$$
with $\tilde{q}$ proportional to the Dirichlet $$\mathfrak D_k(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{k+1})$$density. An acceptance rejection simulation based on this proposal [with acceptance probability $\tilde p(\mathbf x)/\tilde{q}(\mathbf x)$] is thus theoretically able to simulate from $p(\cdot)$ (even though mileage may vary, depending on $\boldsymbol \alpha$ and $\beta$).